# dpkg error processing linux-image after upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, kernel, dpkg

I just upgraded to Ubuntu MATE 18.04 from 16.04. There were some hurdles that I would later describe below, but right now, the upgrade is "complete" except for the following set of errors while dpkg is setting up packages, resulting in failure when trying to update anything.

```
Bus error (core dumped)
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-112-generic (--configure):
 installed linux-image-4.15.0-112-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 135
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-image-generic:
 linux-image-generic depends on linux-image-4.15.0-112-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.15.0-112-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-image-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-112-generic:
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-112-generic depends on linux-image-4.15.0-112-generic | linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-112-generic; however:
  Package linux-image-4.15.0-112-generic is not configured yet.
  Package linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-112-generic is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-112-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-generic:
 linux-generic depends on linux-image-generic (= 4.15.0.112.100); however:
  Package linux-image-generic is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package linux-generic (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-112-generic
 linux-image-generic
 linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-112-generic
 linux-generic
```

I have tried `apt-get install -f`, `apt-get clean`, `apt-get autoremove`, and `dpkg --configure -a` but it's still broken. I haven't tried purging and reinstalling those packages manually in case of a broken download, because these packages look very important.

As for the chronology:

1. I first ran `do-release-upgrade` at work, but I stopped the download quite early on because the Internet wasn't stable.
2. I noticed my Apache is not working properly, so I tried `do-release-upgrade` again. I got a warning saying I should upgrade to the latest patch, and I found that it's "up to date" with around 1500 packages "kept back"
3. After a bit of browsing, I ran `apt-get install -f`. It downloaded around 650mb of packages, and after I restarted, the OS ran but with a broken GUI that looks like Windows 98.
4. I ran `apt-get dist-upgrade` and it downloaded around 1.5gb of packages. After it finished, I rebooted and the OS is working "fine" except the errors above. Though Apache is still not working properly.

I'm sorry if I broke any rule. This is my first post. I'd be really grateful for any help from this community. Right now I'm making a backup of important files in case I end up having to reinstall my Linux, but I really hope I can keep going with this one. Thank you for reading.

Edit: Running `uname -r` shows `4.4.0-187-generic`.

Edit 2: I've purged the older kernels too. The same error still happens.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would suggest that you re-install Ubuntu MATE 18.04. Since you have started making a backup I would suggest that you would continue to do that and then reinstall. You could potentially find a solution but it seems like a lot of work and not worth your while.

You can download the disk image [here](https://ubuntu-mate.org/download/) and then you have to make a bootable media using a USB or DVD. And lastly, install Ubuntu MATE using the bootable media.

Good luck!